# An example of requirements not reflecting user needs

Tags: validation, requirements

I have read that software can pass the verification stage (all requirements are fullfiled) but fail at validation - requirements do not reflect what user wants. 
I cannot think of an example where requirements actually miss the real used needs. (how would such requirements pass the requirement analysis validation?).
I would be grateful for an example, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happens easily if there are implicit requirements.
E.g:
John wants a software that finds the lowest prices of an item on ebay.
He didn't say that he expects the offering to be from his country and should be an auction.